# How to get a picture with text to the right of it

Tags: floats, formatting, captions

what I want is to have a quote like this:

> I returned and saw under the sun, that the race is not to the swift, nor the battle to the strong, neither yet bread to the wise, nor yet riches to men of understanding, nor yet favour to men of skill; but time and chance happeneth to them all.

Then underneath that quote I want a small picture of god, lets take this one

[image]

And to the right of that image of god I want the reference of the quote (above **both** the image and the reference)

> Ecclesiastes 9:11

I can obviously quote the text, and I can put the reference to the right of the image with the `sidecap` package, and I can position the figure under the quote with the `[H]` property. I can also wrap text around images. But apparently `SCfigure` does not accept `H`, and then I get that ugly `Figure. 1` next to the reference, and if there are multiple images there is no guarantee of the outcome. Word wrap also does not guarantee that the reference is next to the correct image. How Can I achieve this in some meaningful way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{displayquote}[][]
I returned and saw under the sun, that the race is not to the swift, nor the battle to the strong, neither yet bread to the wise, nor yet riches to men of understanding, nor yet favour to men of skill; but time and chance happeneth to them all.\par
\begin{minipage}[t]{.35\textwidth}  %% or [b] ?
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{puk}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}     
-- \textit{Ecclesiastes 9:11}
\end{minipage}
\end{displayquote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up selecting yours as the answer as I find it's cleaner and the picture is perfectly aligned with the quote on the left

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need anything other than the graphics package for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}
I returned and saw under the sun, that the race is not to the swift, nor the battle to the strong, neither yet bread to the wise, nor yet riches to men of understanding, nor yet favour to men of skill; but time and chance happeneth to them all.
\end{quote}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l}\includegraphics{g111}\end{tabular}%
\hspace{1em}%
\textrm{Ecclesiastes 9:11}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, is there any way to have the reference line up with the bottom of the image? In mine the image will be much smaller.

Comment: That's easier I added the table to center it:-) `\begin{center}\includegraphics{g111}\hspace{1em}Ecclesiastes 9:11\end{center}`

Comment: PS It's almost always a bad idea to use `[H]` (`H` was my idea:(

Comment: Hi it's still not lining up with the bottom of the image

Comment: it's not a big deal though, I just made the image smaller. Also, I removed center as its not something I wanted. Thank you

Comment: the baseline of \includegraphics is its bottom edge so that will line up with the baseline of Ecclesiastes  if you use it as in the comment above not in a tabular (which is only in my answer to centre the image vertically_